# Can't scale properly to android device in Game Maker Studio 1.4

Tags: android, game-maker, resolution

My phone is using a resolution of `360 x 640` with a `9:16` aspect ratio. I set my room in game maker to `360 x 640`  and game maker thinks it's in landscape mode. I disabled landscape mode in the android settings and set to portrait only, like it should be. How do I get it to scale properly?

This is the code I have in my Scale Manager Object.

Create Event:

```
///Display Properties
ideal_width = 0;
ideal_height = 640;

aspect_ratio = display_get_width()/display_get_height();
ideal_width = round(ideal_height/aspect_ratio);

//check for odd numbers
if(ideal_width & 1) {
    ideal_width++;
}

for (var i = 1; i <= room_last; i++) {
    if(room_exists(i)) {
        room_set_view(i,0,true,0,0,ideal_width,ideal_height,0,0,ideal_width,ideal_height,0,0,0,0,-1);
        room_set_view_enabled(i,true);
    }
}

surface_resize(application_surface,ideal_width , ideal_height);
window_set_size(ideal_width,ideal_height);
room_goto(room_next(room));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched the variables locations in this line

```
ideal_width = round(ideal_height/aspect_ratio);
```

Now it's

```
ideal_height = round(ideal_width/aspect_ratio);
```