# How do I scale room transition surfaces to fit mobile display?

Tags: android, game-maker, graphic-effects

I followed a tutorial on how to add a left swipe room transition, which works very well. My problem is that it won't scale to my Android display. I know that it's being drawn to the GUI layer and I've tried resizing the GUI to the display width and height but I didn't see any changes. It's a really nice effect that I want to get working for my game.

Create Event:

```
currentframe = 0
maxframes = 45

persistent = true; // when changing room keep this object alive

// copy the old room so we can display it on the second room
sur_oldroom = surface_create(room_width,room_height);
surface_copy(sur_oldroom,0,0,application_surface);

// We have recorded what the old room looks like so we can instantly go to the next room.
room_goto(rm_game);
```

Destroy Event:

```
surface_free(sur_newroom)
surface_free(sur_oldroom)
```

Step Event:

```
currentframe++

if (currentframe > maxframes) {
    instance_destroy() // The transition has finished so destroy it
}


// We are now on the second room so record that room. 
if (currentframe == 2) { 
    sur_newroom = surface_create(room_width,room_height);
    surface_copy(sur_newroom,0,0,application_surface);
}
```

Draw GUI Event:

```
if (currentframe > 1) {

    // convert the number of frames that have passed into a number between 0 and the room width
    var slideamount = EaseOutQuad(currentframe,0,room_width,maxframes)

    if (surface_exists(sur_oldroom)) {
        draw_surface(sur_oldroom,-slideamount,0)
    }

    if (surface_exists(sur_newroom)) {
        draw_surface(sur_newroom,room_width-slideamount,0)
    }
}


/// I do this to hide the flicker where the next room pops up for 1 frame 
if (currentframe == 1) { 
    if (surface_exists(sur_oldroom)) {
        draw_surface(sur_oldroom,0,0)
    }
}
```

I'm using Game Maker Studio 1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like the boy crying wolf, so sorry for that. Next time I encounter a problem, I'll just post it as how to fix that problem. Anyways in my screen manager object related to this post here: [Can't scale properly to android device in Game Maker Studio 1.4](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/159919/cant-scale-properly-to-android-device-in-game-maker-studio-1-4), My solution was `display_set_gui_size(ideal_width,ideal_height);` after the line `surface_resize(application_surface,ideal_width , ideal_height);`